# Android multitouch View.OnTouchListener

Tags: android, multi-touch

Im trying to play around with some multitouch in Android.

I have two RelativeLayout on screen where I would like to get touch events.

```
fooLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.foo);
fooLayout.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);

barLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bar);
barLayout.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);

...

View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ...
```

I tried having a OnTouchListener for each layout but that didn't seem to work at all.

I figured since the onTouch method gets an View I would be able to make out with view the current touch event came from and save away the pointer id.

```
int pointerId = event.getPointerId(event.getActionIndex());
int action = event.getActionMasked();
switch (action) {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
          switch (v.getId()) {
               case R.id.foo:
                    fooPointerId = pointerId;
                    break;
               case R.id.bar:
                    barPointerId = pointerId;
                    break;
}
```

This does not work as I thought it would.
When my first finger touches in one of the layouts I will get the correct id from that layout. But when I put down a second finger in the other layout it will get the id of the layout where I put down my first finger.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Is this possible to do or do I have to put the OnTouchListener on the top view and figure out which layout Im touching by the x/y values of the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should extend relative layout and implement onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) over there to figure out which pointers are touching which child views(Put foo and bar inside your main relative layout/view group that implements onTouchEvent).

IMO onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) only lets you register one pointer at a time so it may not be possible using this approach. This [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) might help out

Comment: I did a quick test making 2 custom views on overriding the onTouchEvent. If I touch and hold on one view and then touch on the other that event wont dispatch. All the examples Ive seen so far, including the link seems to be multitouch within one view. Is there no way to make it work with multiple views?

Comment: Try extending a view group such as relative layout then in your XML put that as your root and add your views inside it. Implement onTouchEvent on the root. I think that way all the child views will be exposed to multiple pointers.

Comment: So I would have to determine which view the touch is located in using the x/y values of the event in the "root"?

Comment: Yes and you can even know by pointerIds which pointer is on which view

Comment: Ok, that was what I was afraid of. Was hoping to find away around this. Thanks for the help.